# How can I put an icon inside a snackbar using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter, I don't know if it is possible to do this. I would like to put an icon on the left side of the text.

```
SnackBar(    
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  content: Text(_accion_toast + ". " + mensaje),
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
);
```

Answer (score 9):

The `content` property of the `Snackbar` takes a `Widget`.

In your case, you can pass the `Row` widget since you want to place items side by side( your icon and your text).

Check the code below, it works fine:

```
   SnackBar(
      // background color of your snack-bar
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      // make the content property take a Row
      content: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          // add your preferred icon here
          Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          // add your preferred text content here
          Text(_accion_toast + ". " + mensaje),
        ],
      ),
      // the duration of your snack-bar
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the content parameter of the `SnackBar` to a row containing first the `Icon` and then the `Text`. An example:

```
SnackBar(    
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  content: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      //Icon widget of your choice HERE,
      Text(_accion_toast + ". " + mensaje)
    ]
  ),
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
);
```